# UIBarButtonItem action method not being called

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I've been trying to get this bit of code to work for a while and have done bit of research online to see what could be causing the problem and think something could potentially be blocking the action taking place.

I've placed this bit of code in the `viewDidLoad` and then the `viewWillAppear:` methods but it doesn't work.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goMenu)];
```

I have also tried adding break points in the `goMenu` method which doesn't get called.

Any help with this will be much appreciated as I don't know why it wouldn't be getting called.

Comment: Change `backBarButtonItem` to `leftBarButtonItem`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add target to stock back button in navigationBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065235/add-target-to-stock-back-button-in-navigationbar)

Comment: The leftBarButtonItem worked thanks, I thought I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goMenu)];
```

Please replace backBarButtonItem to leftBarButtonItem.

This piece of code will work...

Comment: Thanks mate, someone answered this in the comments too.