# How to imitate stock back button

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I want to add an Action to my standard Back-Button, but this won't work as I found from below link:

[add-target-to-stock-back-button-in-navigationbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065235/add-target-to-stock-back-button-in-navigationbar)

So I created a custom button with an action.

```
UIBarButtonItem(title: "❮ Back", style: .Bordered, target: self, action: "back:")
```

But how can I set the standard left wing to the title?

The character '❮' is way smaller than that from the standard button. I use the standard button throughout my app, and I want to keep this optic.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34343418/4910767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "add" some functionality to your back button you can use the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

When you press the back button, the navigation controller will call `navigationController(willShowViewController:)` so you can use this to do whatever you want to do. An example is shown below:

**Using UINavigationControllerDelegate:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        // Add whatever you want to do here
    }
}
```